# Asynchronous Finding Closest Match

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, difference, difflib

I am looking for a way to find the closest matches in a list.

Until now, I'd use difflib for this, but difflib is blocking for Asynchronous code and I need something which, does not have to be too fast, but which is does Support Async.

Comment: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: This is not what I needed @AchilleG

Comment: This is not a premade answer but it can definitly help you out